# Api Requests failing with playwright using Java

Tags: java, api, playwright

I am trying to learn Playwright for api and web testing using Java. So far with api testing I am getting a weird issue where I am getting the following errors for all of my requests:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code:

```
        Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
        APIRequestContext request;
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request = playwright.request()
                .newContext(new APIRequest.NewContextOptions()
                        .setBaseURL("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/store")
                        .setExtraHTTPHeaders(headers)
                );
        Map<String, String> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("id","400");
        body.put("petId","731368479");
        body.put("quantity", "4");
        body.put("status","placed");
        body.put("complete", "true");
        APIResponse addNewPet = request.post("/order",
                RequestOptions.create().setData(body));
        System.out.println(addNewPet.text());
//        assertTrue(addNewPet.ok());
//        assertEquals(200, addNewPet.status());

        playwright.close();
```

I am not sure where and what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working if you add the slash at the end of the baseURL and remove it from the post url:

```
...
.setBaseURL("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/store/")
...
APIResponse addNewPet = request.post("order",
...
```

Comment: Strange, but yea moving the slash up to base URL make it work. Thanks :)